# Quantify measure of oscillations in periodic time series data

Tags: time-series, fast-fourier-transform

I have a periodic time series data that are constantly sent to server from machines. It has uneven sampling rate.

I want to quantify measure of oscillations by combining information about frequency + amplitude of oscillations.

To my knowledge, Fourier transformation handles this, but it works only when the sampling rate is constant. Mine is not, which forced me to use Lomb-Scargle transformation to extract information about dominant frequency. Unfortunately, Lomb-Scargle periodogram does not preserve the amplitude of the original data.

I tried both FFT and Lomb-Scarlge. FFT completely failed, but Lomb-Scargle succeeded in capturing dominant frequencies, but still, did not preserve amplitude of the original data

So I want to scale my Lomb-scargle periodogram so that it contains information about the amplitude of the original data.

Consider the following time series:

[image]

I want to capture information about amplitude of oscillation, and how often that occurs with:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{\Delta y_i}{t_i}}=(\frac{\Delta y_1}{\Delta t_1} + \frac{\Delta y_2}{\Delta t_2} + \frac{\Delta y_3}{\Delta t_3} \, \cdots \, \frac{\Delta y_N}{\Delta t_N}) / (1 - N)$$

Is this a valid approach? I am concerned that the sampling rate is uneven, and it might affect my approach. And also the change in amplitude is affected by when it was recorded. For example, $\Delta y_2$ and $\Delta y_3$ are captures over the similar $\Delta t$, and yet the absolute difference in magnitude is largely different.

If my approach is not right, is there any other suggestions?

Comment: You could also create your fourier transform by hand using $F(\omega)=\sum e^{-i\omega t} f(t)$ for a certain range in $\omega$. But the computation could be time consuming...

Comment: @E.Bellec Fourier transformation does not work because I have uneven sampling rate

Comment: Fast Fourier transforms require even sampling, but regular Fourier transform does not.

Comment: @Andrei Does discrete Fourier preserve information about the amplitude of the original data?

Comment: I'm a python developer, so I don't know too much about math

Comment: The math works out. The issue is that you need to know what is the expected frequency range. In FFT you have a step in frequency given by the size of the time domain, and you have a maximum frequency given by the time step. You don't have that information with the regular FT. You need to add those as an input

Comment: Maybe this would help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform  But as @Andrei said, I would compute the regular FT if it is not time consuming.

Comment: If I understood your problem, you practically are looking for interpolating a number of points $(x_k,y_k)$ with a sum of sines of  unknown amplitude, frequency and phase. What do you know in advance about frequencies, can you discretize them ?

Comment: @GCab No, its not the sum of sines that I'm looking for. The diagram I drew is just my idea (which im not sure if its right) to come up with a metric that quantifies fluctuations in time series data. What I mean by "fluctuation" is frequency of oscillation + amplitude combined.

Comment: @GCab I posted the same question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415903/quantify-measure-of-oscillation-and-amplitude-in-time-series-data/415906#415906) too, with extra descriptions

Comment: Also in the other post, it is not very clear to me what you want to do: the answer you got there is in fact in line with the one I was thinking about. Give a simple example, and show which would be the "function" that meet you requirements.